# How to use urlencode in a hyperlink using phpmysql

Tags: php, hyperlink

Can you please tell me how to use  urlencode in a hyperlink. I have a mysql database and it saves queries from users. This queries will be showed in my website and i want when another user click to this hyperlink it will go to google search.Because these queries contains space,i read in net that using urlencode will convert this space into 20.Below is my code.

```
echo("<br><a target=_blank href=www.google.com/search?q=urlencode($link[link]) class=z>$link[link]</a>");
```

This code has two problems

1. It will open as a continuation of my website.
   instead of `www.google.com/search?q=query`,
   it opens as `www.mysite.com/www.google.com/search?q=query`
2. Because i added urlencode in `$link[link]` the website opening is `www.mysite.com/www.google.com/search?q=urlencode(query)`.

urlencode also goes into the search term.

Answer (score 1):

remove the call from the string and concatenate the result to it, that should do it

```
echo("<br><a target=_blank href='www.google.com/search?q=".urlencode($link[link])."' class=z>$link[link]</a>");
```

edit, I added some quotes around the url as well

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the `href` attribute containing an absolute url to solve #1 and to break the string and use the concatenation for getting the url urlencoded to solve problem #2:

```
   echo("<br><a target=_blank href='http://www.google.com/search?q=" . urlencode($link[link]) . "' class=z>{$link['link']}</a>");
```

- Third: you need to use brackets when you use an array in string interpolation
- Fourth: you should use quotes to surround array keys to avoid notices

The following become:

```
class=z>$link[link]</a>     # this is wrong
class=z>{$link['link']}</a> # should be this
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php